# A question about $G$- invariant polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-polynomials

I'm trying to understand the following.

Let's consider $G \le S_n$.
We define a $G$-invariant function as $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$f(g\cdot x) =f(x) \, \, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \, , \forall g \in G.$$

The action of the group on $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as follows:

$$g \cdot x := (x_{g^{-1}(1)}, \dots , x_{g^{-1}(n)}).$$

The $G$-invariant *polynomials*  are all polynomials that are also $G$-invariant functions and we denote them as $\mathbb{R}[x_1, \dots ,x_n]^G$.

What I want to prove is that given $p \in \mathbb{R}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ a polynomial that is not necessarily $G$-invariant, then

$$q(x) = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}p(g \cdot x)$$

is $G$-invariant.

Comment: How does $G$ act on $\mathbb{R}^n$?  Permutation of coordinates?

Comment: Yes sorry I have updated the question with the action of the group. It's indeed the permutation of coordinates.

Comment: Your definition of "$G$-invariant" needs a $\forall g$?

Comment: Hint: the terms of the sum for $q(g_0\cdot x)$ are just the terms of $q(x)$ permuted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard "averaging" argument.  Given $h \in G$, you want to show that $q(h.x) = q(x)$.  You have

$$q(h.x)  = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum\limits_{g \in G} p(gh.x)).$$

This is just adding all the terms $p(gh.x)$, as $g$ runs through all the distinct elements of $G$.  But since multiplication by $h$ permutes the elements of $G$, this is the same as just adding all the terms $p(g.x)$, as $g$ runs through the distinct elements of $G$.

This argument shows up a lot in representation theory, for example if you have a representation $\pi$ of a compact topological group $G$ on Hilbert space $V$ with inner product $\langle -,- \rangle$, you can always replace the inner product with an equivalent inner product which is $G$-invariant by defining

$$\langle v, w \rangle_1 = \frac{1}{\operatorname{volume}(G)}\int\limits_G \langle \pi(g)v, \pi(g)w \rangle \space dg.$$

Comment: many thanks, by the way it is not yet 100% clear. So since we 'compose' $g \circ h$ we end up in a new permutation let's say $s := gh$ and then $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{s \in G}p(s \cdot x)$  but I still can't figure out why do we need the $\frac{1}{|G|}$...

Comment: You don't need the term $\frac{1}{|G|}$ term, the argument would have worked if you had instead defined $q(x) = \sum_{g \in G} p(g.x)$.  It is just a convention.